# Methods not responding after UIAlerView button pressed

Tags: objective-c, methods, uialertview, instance-variables

I have this problem where I show an alert view and then after a button is pressed certain methods should run but neither would.

```
- (void)insertNewObject //Works fine
{
//AlertView is a subclass of UIAlertView I created.
    AlertView *al = [AlertView alloc];
    al = [al initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:[self view] cancelButtonTitle:@"cencel" okButtonTitle:@"ok"];
    [al.titlebox becomeFirstResponder];

    //[view setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [al show];
} /Till here everything works fine.
```

All the code below here dont work. Or they work, I just dont know coz they dont run.

```
//This method does no run al all.
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex2
{

    if(buttonIndex2 == 0)
    {
        _buttonIndex = buttonIndex2;
        [self showAbortAlert];

    } else 
    {
    _buttonIndex = buttonIndex2;
        [self addObject];
    }
}

- (void)addObject 
{
    if(_buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
    //[newManagedObject setValue:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>];
    //[newManagedObject setValue:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>];

    // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    } else {
        [self showAbortAlert];
    }
}

- (void)showAbortAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Aborted" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleDefault];
    [alert show];
}
```

No compilation errors.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this fixes all your problems, but in the code example you gave, you are probably setting the delegate falsely to the view, when you want it to be the ViewController:

That is, instead of:

```
al = [al initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:[self view] cancelButtonTitle:@"cencel" okButtonTitle:@"ok"];
```

you probably want to do this:

```
al = [al initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cencel" okButtonTitle:@"ok"];
```

Also, since you alloc'ed the alert, don't forget to release it after you've called show.

```
//some code here

[al show];
[al release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try it now. I dont have to release, I have ARC turn on and ARC "forbids" [release];

Comment: LOL can't believe it was something that simple, thanks though! Always the simple things that escapes me.